# Detect type of post status transition

Tags: hooks, actions, post-status

I have a function on my site that it supposed to run when a new post is published (email push notification), with the exception of the same article updated (i.e `publish_to_publish` transition, I don't want to send unnecessary push notifications)

I know that I can use the {old_status}  to  {new_status} action hooks, but this means that I have to specify all the transitions to `publish` (`new_to_publish`, `draft_to_publish`, etc.).

My question is:

1. Can I use instead the `publish_post` hook and detect if it was `publish_to_publish` so I can explicitly negate it?  something like:

   ```
   function send_email() {
    if ($transition == 'publish_to_publish') return;
     //(else) send email
   }
     add_action('publish_post', 'send_email', 10, 1);
   ```
2. If not, how do I tie multiple hooks to the same action? Do I just list them like so:

   ```
   add_action('new_to_publish', 'send_mail', 10, 1);
   add_action('future_to_publish', 'send_mail', 10, 1);
   add_action('draft_to_publish', 'send_mail', 10, 1);
   ```

Or is there a more elegant way - like passing an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If not, how do I tie multiple hooks to the same action? Do I just list
>   them like so:
>
> ```
> add_action('new_to_publish', 'save_new_post', 10, 1);
> add_action('future_to_publish', 'save_new_post', 10, 1);
> add_action('draft_to_publish', 'save_new_post', 10, 1);
> ```

This is exactly the way to go. Just hook the same callback into each of the status-transition hooks on which you want the callback to fire.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this is one hook by using the [`transition_post_status`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/transition_post_status/). All we need to do is to check that the old status is not `publish`. We can also exclude other statuses by creating an array of these statuses and check against `$old_status`

Note, this requires PHP 5.4+ and is untested

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', function ( $new_status, $old_status, $post )
{
    // First check if our new status is publish before we do any work
    if ( 'publish' !== $new_status )
        return;

    // Create the array of post statuses to check against
    $statuses = ['publish', 'pending', 'private', 'trash'];

    // If the old status is an the $statuses array, bail
    if ( in_array( $old_status, $statuses ) )
        return;

    // Everything checked out, lets do what we are suppose to do
    // send email
}, 10, 3 );
```