# How to auto update post title and slug with category name when post status is updated

Tags: categories, slug, title

I need to auto update post title and slug with category name every time when post status is updated. Some function like this but with the correct code....

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data','reset_post_date',99,2);
   function reset_post_date($data,$postarr) {

   $data['post_title'] = How to add category name here?

 //also update the slug of the post for the URL
     $data['post_name'] = wp_unique_post_slug( sanitize_title( $data['post_title'] ), $postarr['ID'], $data['post_status'], $data['post_type'], $data['post_parent'] );
     return $data;
  }
```

### EDIT

I tried by myself but without success. Now I'm trying to run this function only when status is changed from draft to publish...but again no success.

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'my_modify_title', 10, 2 );
 function my_modify_title( $title, $id ) {
  if( in_category( 'My Category', $id ) ) {
   $title = 'My Category';
 }
  if( in_category( 'New Category', $id ) ) {
   $title = 'New Category';
 }
return $title;
}
```

and

```
add_action('draft_to_publish', 'my_modify_title', 10, 2);
```

how to add filter and action in one function to make it work together?

Comment: then you need to learn "how to get category name ?"

Answer (score 0):

You need [post status transitions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions), and quite similar with this post:

- [Detect type of post status transition](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87948/detect-type-of-post-status-transition)

only what you need to do update post title and slug, and this is easy.

[Update post examples](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post)

---

Since you wrote like this:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'my_modify_title', 10, 2 );
 function my_modify_title( $title, $id ) {
  if( in_category( 'My Category', $id ) ) {
   $title = 'My Category';
 }
  if( in_category( 'New Category', $id ) ) {
   $title = 'New Category';
 }
return $title;
}
```

Note that [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) is saying  'the_title' should work only inside the loop. I would never update slugs inside loop. The loop looks to me more like a way to draw the post content.

Also note, if trying to update the title:

```
$title = $title. "My Category";
```

would be more common.

What I would suggest:

```
add_action('draft_to_publish', 'my_modify_title', 10, 2);
function my_modify_title ($post){
   // your work to update post slug and title.

    $current_title = $post->post_title;
    $current_slug = $post->post_name;

    $new_slug = ...;
    $new_title = ...;



    wp_update_post(
        array (
            'ID'        => $post->ID,
            'post_name' => $new_slug, 
            'post_title'=> $new_title
        )
    );

   return;    
}
```

And you have the last code inside your functions.php or some even better place.

Check out this [ref](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post):